# Spring Security OAuth2 cookies

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have OAuth2 implemented in my app with Spring Security. Currently, it works with the "access_token" request parameter. Where can I add some customization to also accept the token from a cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the token from a Cookie - using oAuth, the only way to get it is via a call to the oAuth server, getting a code, and then getting the token...
You can read the [oAuth spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

If you talk about the application-end (and not the oAuth), it might be possible.
Checking the token is the responsibility of the application that holds the protexcted resource. There, rather than getting the token from the header of the request, it can check a Cookie instead.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. After I have already obtained the token via the normal oAuth flow, I would like to be authorized via cookie instead of via request parameter.